# Cannot integrate JProfiler with Java Project in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, profiling, jprofiler

While trying to integrate a Java web app maven project deployed on Tomcat with Jprofiler's Netbeans based plugin I see this message:

```
For free-form projects, you need to execute the debug action
once before profiling is possible. When executing the debug action
for the first time, a debug target will be generated in a separate
build file.
```

Even when I tried to profile after deploying the project in debug mode, this still displays the same message? How do I rectify this ?

Comment: is your project a maven project or ant freeform one? the message suggests the latter while your question implies the former. This could be an erro on jprofiler side, not properly recognizing the maven projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 8.0.1, maven projects are not supported by the JProfiler Netbeans module. This will be implemented in a future version, possibly in 8.1.